# How to use canvas without import task module in celery client?

Tags: celery

Suppose that we have a caller `A` and a callee `B`. `B` implements some function and has heavy dependencies.

Typically, I don't want to import these dependencies in `A` to keep it lightweight.

Previously, I can happily use `send_task` to call `B` by name.

Now I have more complex logic and wanna orchestrate tasks with canvas. Following the user guide [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html):

`signature('tasks.add', args=(2, 2), countdown=10)`

I got a task `NotRegistered` error.

How to register task by name?

Comment: We still need to see a lot of code from you before we can help, i.e., what does the task `B` looks like in coding?  What are the arguments it takes and how is it decorated?  What is the configuration of your celery.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, we can't actually help you.  So I'll answer your question generically using the docs:

For reference, here is the example snippet from celery:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('tasks', broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def add(x, y):
    return x + y
```

Note that we create the signature `tasks.add` because the application is named `tasks` in the `Celery` constructor and the function is named `add`.  This task is registered because it is in a tasks.py file.  So, to call a task by name we have to make sure of three things:

1. Is the task registered properly?  We can check by looking at the output when a celery worker starts, and the worker outputs a list of registered tasks.  If not, make sure the task is in a tasks.py file or a `tasks` module that celery knows to look for.
2. What is my application name?  We can find this by looking for the call to the `Celery` constructor.  It is what you pass to the `-A` parameter when starting a worker.
3. What is my task name?  If no name is specified in the `app.task` decorator, use the function name.  Otherwise use the `name` specified in the `app.task` decorator.

After ensuring (1), concatenate (2) and (3), and put a `.` in between them to get the task name to call.

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. I get it working by manually declaring all tasks in each worker and client app config. It seems that a celery app can not get registered from broker and need manually declaration? here is the demo: https://github.com/misssprite/celery_canvas_demo